# sed awk truncate to wrap a line and chose specific fields

Tags: sed

I have 3 lines like this in a file

```
this is the first line blah1 blah2 
this is the next line 0.101 0.202 0.303
this is the answer 0.404
```

### Desired

```
this is the first line 0.202 0.303 -0.404
```

Can this be achieved using sed/awk/truncate (tr) etc ? in a line or two ?

Comment: I need more information in order to help you.

Comment: I updated my description of the request

Comment: What are the rules? Why do you skip `0.101`? Why is there a minus sign before `0.404`? Why do you keep `this is the first line` but not `blah1 blah2`? Please, [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1811607/edit) your question and add real file content.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure if this is what you want, but here goes.

Your file

```
this is the first line blah1 blah2
this is the next line 0.101 0.202 0.303
this is the answer 0.404
```

Replace "blah1 blah2" with "0.202 0.303 -0.404"

```
sed -i 's/blah1 blah2/0.202 0.303 -0.404/' file
```

or this

```
sed -i 's/blah1/0.202/' -i 's/blah2/0.303 -0.404/' file
```

Contents of file

```
this is the first line 0.202 0.303 -0.404
this is the next line 0.101 0.202 0.303
this is the answer 0.404
```

If this is not what you want give more details and I will adjust my answer.